# How to override multiple console function? (console.log, console.info etc)

Tags: javascript, console, overriding

I have learned the way to override console.log by following the tutorial:

```
var log = console.log;

    console.log = function(){
            blablabla
            log.apply(console, args);
        
    }
```

What if I want to override not only console.log, but also console.info, .error etc? Is there an efficient way to do so?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no other way than assign a new function to each property already holding a function doing it one by one. Unless you meant to assign the same exact function to all those properties (log, error, debug...). In that case you define the function once and you assign it to every property one by one

Comment: @DiegoDeVita erm...why? Loops and various other iteration options exist.

Comment: @VLAZ I meant in terms of correspondence. oh yes if you meant to loop over all the properties of a given object and assign them a value by criteria you can do it.. I was doing some assumptions in my thoughts toward the solution

Comment: Maybe I should explain more on my situation. I have created my own function to enhance  console.log by the above method (includes timestamp, stack) and I would like to apply it to console.info, console.warn and console.error as well. I am struggling at finding an efficient way to do this.

Comment: @Unfabulous I would advise against this. You should not be modifying global objects. Not in any sort of serious code. There are all kinds of unanticipated side-effects that might result in this. Worse yet, they might only show up months or years later. Maybe the definition for globals changed. Maybe you had some other library (could even be yours) that also tries to modify them. There could be functionality that relies on unmodified globals implicitly or explicitly. If you want some sort of custom logger, then *create one* and then use it in your code. guaranteed to not interfere with anything

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the use case but you can just loop over the console properties.

```js
const log = console.log;// Keep reference to the log function.

// Loop over each property.
for(const key in console) {
  // Overwrite all functions to log.
  if(typeof console[key] === 'function') {
    console[key] = log;
  }
}

console.table("I'm not a table, I actually just log...");
```

If you want to overwrite just a few functions you can also create some sort of whitelist.

```js
const log = console.log;// Keep reference to the log function.
const whitelist = ['log', 'info', 'error', 'table'];

// Loop over whitelist.
for(const key of whitelist) {
  // Overwrite all functions to log.
  if(typeof console[key] === 'function') {
    console[key] = log;
  }
}

console.table("I'm not a table, I actually just log...");
```

Comment: for how the question is asked that's the only approach I can think of as well.. at the same time I would warn that `console` have many properties holding a function going beyond trivial logging that would make no sense to override that way [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console)

Answer (score 0):

You can override console by a Proxy (I don't recommend) :

```js
console = ((dict = {}) => new Proxy(console, {
    get(console, key){
      if(typeof console[key] === 'function') {
        return dict[key] ?? (dict[key] = (...args) => {
            console.log('blablabla')
            return console[key](...args)
        })
      }
      return console[key]
    }
}))()
```